# How to get frequent Timestamps between an early and a late daytime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have a df with an index of millions of timestamps which maintain a frequent stamping
(eg. every 5 minutes)

**but with holes**.

(= some timestamps in the ideal order **are missing**, maybe even over the whole dataframe,

for example '20:05:00' might never come up, though its neighbours '20:00:00' & '20:10:00' could exist.).

.

I need to get those "holes". But **only those between a specific early-daytime and a specific late-daytime.**

```
Time                 Vals
2019-06-17 08:45:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 08:50:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 08:55:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:00:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:05:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:10:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:15:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:20:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:25:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:30:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:35:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:40:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:45:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:50:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 09:55:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:00:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:05:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:10:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:15:00   NaN 
2019-06-17 10:20:00   NaN 
                ...   ...
                ...   ...
                ...   ...
Name: Vals, dtype: float64
```

One can get the early daytime and the late daytime by the following:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(X.index.date,X.index.time))

# get unique times 
dates = X.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
times = X.index.get_level_values(1).unique()

early_daytime = times.min
late_daytime  = times.max

# back to original index format: reduce MultiIndex to 1D datetime index, sort
X.index = [datetime.combine(date,time) for date,time in X.index.values]
X = X.sort_index()
```

Lets say the pseudo frequency would be 5 minutes.

How can I get every "in the frequent order of 5 min" missing timestamp **for every day that is contained in "dates"** and **between "early_daytime" and "late_daytime"**?

Note: The variable *"times"* or the *index* could **not contain 100% of the day-time** values which should be included in the frequent order of 5 minutes. (= the holes I mentioned earlier)

Is there a way to do that efficiently (because of the large amount of rows)?

EDIT: this is a different Question that the one before, so please dont close it when not read carefully.

EDIT:
When I have a specific early-daytime and a specific late-daytime for some each weekday how to apply it?

(this could be done by splitting again into multi-index, then selecting the earliest and latest date, {step i dont know how to integrate}, and then uniting the resulted timeindices at the end of the loop.) But how to integrate this step I put into curvy brackets?
I didnt test it yet on my sample but @Rob Raymond suggestion might be the step i dont know how to integrate in the weekday approach...

```
dfse = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":pd.date_range(start=datetime(2020,7,24),end=datetime(2020,7,25), freq="5min")})\
    .merge(dfgaps, how="left").loc[lambda df: df["value"].isna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to achieve with a `merge()`

1. synthesised a dataframe that has some holes in it
2. find missing times on shorter `date_range()`
3. output shows it works as it's less than number of total holes
4. adding index *dffind* and then `merge()` is slower than no index.  Showed timing and simulated rows.  Plus results where found is a subset of missing as it's only search between 04:00 and 16:00

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import time
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'DATE':d, "value":random.randint(0,10)}
        for d in pd.date_range(start=datetime(2013,1,1),end=datetime(2020,3,24), freq="5min")\
         .union(pd.date_range(start=datetime(2020,4,1),end=datetime(2020,7,24), freq="5min"))
         .union(pd.date_range(start=datetime(2012,7,1),end=datetime(2012,7,2), freq="5min"))

    ])
# randomly "remove" from dataset so there are gaps
mask = df.index.isin([random.randint(0, len(df)) for r in range(10)])
dfgaps = df.loc[~mask]

# date_range which is all of the dates that exist in source dataframe
start = time.time()
dt = dfgaps["DATE"].dt.floor("D").unique()
dr = None
for i,d in enumerate(dt):
    # only expand in contiguous ranges
    if i==0 or (i<len(dt)-1 and d+np.timedelta64(1, "D")==dt[i+1]) or (d>dt[i-1]+np.timedelta64(1, "D")):
        temp = pd.date_range(start=d, end=d+(np.timedelta64(1, "D")-np.timedelta64(1, "m")), freq="5min")
        dr = temp if dr is None else dr.union(temp)
# date_range to dataframe NB hour>=n and hour<=m to only find between desired times
dffind = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":[t for t in dr if t.hour>=4 and t.hour<=16]})

# pick out missing items from shorter start/end date
dfse = dffind.merge(dfgaps, how="left", on="DATE").loc[lambda df: df["value"].isna()]
print(f"Execution Time: {time.time() - start:.2f}s Rows:{len(df):,}")
print(f"Missing:\n{df[mask].to_string(index=False)}\nFound:\n{dfse.to_string(index=False)}")
```

**output**

```
Execution Time: 27.92s Rows:793,155
Missing:
               DATE  value
2013-01-02 23:45:00      4
2013-09-27 14:20:00      8
2014-04-26 12:35:00      0
2015-05-06 20:55:00      1
2016-07-30 21:20:00      5
2016-10-09 18:10:00      2
2017-12-26 04:20:00      2
2018-11-06 19:50:00      3
2018-12-14 15:40:00      8
2019-09-29 06:25:00      9
Found:
               DATE  value
2013-09-27 14:20:00    NaN
2014-04-26 12:35:00    NaN
2017-12-26 04:20:00    NaN
2018-12-14 15:40:00    NaN
2019-09-29 06:25:00    NaN
```

Comment: for clarification: 1. does this only include the values between the "early_daytime" and the "late_daytime" from above? how efficient is this on a large index (mio of rows) or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Im not sure if were on the same track. maybe I forgot to mention: the input index does only contatin specific weekdays. (for example in some cases no weekends, in some cases just sundays or tuesdays.

Comment: in this example 2020/7/24 is *early_date* and 2020/7/25 is *late_date*.  if instead you want between 04:00 and 08:00 it's easy to do when building set of expected value.  I trust `merge()` to be more efficient that any looping code.  It would be improved if *DATE* was made the index instead of a column.  Update your question and I'm happy to update the answer

Comment: Smart idea^^ so DATE could also be an intraday column. (When using multiindexing this way the specific matches could be filtered out for the days too i guess, do you have an Idea how to do that?) i'll update the question right now

Comment: @Iroquois_Pliskin I've updated the answer.  It now uses all the dates that exist is source dataframe and sub-selects on time of day that you want to find